# userManager.FindByIdAsync returns NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, reset-password

I dont know why my userManager.FindByIdAsync returns a NULL value when a trying reset my password.

```
public async Task<bool> ResetPasswordByAdmin(string userId, string newPassword)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                string token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                var identityResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword);
                return identityResult.Succeeded;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

EDIT 01 (FindByIdAsync):

```
    public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Retrieves the user associated with the specified external login provider and
    //     login provider key.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   loginProvider:
    //     The login provider who provided the providerKey.
    //
    //   providerKey:
    //     The key provided by the loginProvider to identify a user.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The System.Threading.Tasks.Task for the asynchronous operation, containing the
    //     user, if any which matched the specified login provider and key.
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, what is _userManager.FindByIdAsync() doing? Can you provide the code for that? As it is, there's not enough code here to reproduce your issue.

Comment: In your database, userId type is really string type? If not, converting string userId input to same type as be in the database should be solve problem. For example, if your database userId type is int, you can convert it by using Convert.ToInt32() function like that  ````var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync((Convert.ToIn32(userId));````

Comment: @onurkanBakırcı thank you!!